# Test failing for feature that works using assert_changes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, minitest

My chat app has a chat class and a message class; when a message is added to the chat, chat.updated_at should also be updated (achieved with `belongs_to :chat, touch: true`).

When I test this manually, it works correctly, the time is updated. My test below fails however, and I cannot work out why.

```
  test "sending a message should update chats updated timestamp" do
    sign_in @user
    assert_changes "@chat.updated_at" do
      post messages_path(params: { message: { 
        text: 'Hello', to_id: @bob.id, chat_id: @chat.id
        }})
      assert_response :success
    end
  end
```

I simply get the error `@chat.updated_at` didn't change.

My chat fixture is

```
one:
  id: 1
  subject: nil
  updated_at: <%= 2.hours.ago %>
```

Comment: do you have to use the assert_changes?

Comment: Is there a better way to assert the time is updated? Or a reason assert_changes doesn't work here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should use model.reload https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Persistence/reload

```
assert_changes "@chat.reload.updated_at" do
```

Explanation:
Once a Rails model is loaded from DB, when you access an attribute it will use the values that were already read and not make the same query again and again (unless explicitly told to do so with reload). And in your test, Ruby simply compares `@chat.updated_at` before and after but there is no second query on the second time, simply a cached attribute

Comment: Would this do two database queries?

Answer (score 0):

You need to reload the record from the database to get the object in your test to reflect the changes that were performed in the database:

```
  test "sending a message should update chats updated timestamp" do
    sign_in @user
    assert_changes "@chat.updated_at" do
      post messages_path(params: { message: { 
        text: 'Hello', to_id: @bob.id, chat_id: @chat.id
        }})
      @chat.reload
      assert_response :success
    end
  end
```

Remember that `@chat` in your test and controller point to completely different objects in memory.